# How to create different templates for woocommerce single-product.php?

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, css, html

I am learning Wordpress development. I have 3 products that I want to add to my woocommerce store.

By default woocommerce store comes with a basic template for all products. But I want to make every single product different just like apple.com does in their single product pages by explaining with parallax scrolling effect.

Can you please tell me how can I create different single-product.php files each for 3 different product.

Or what's the best way of doing this?